# How to create png image from QGraphicsScene in one click on a button

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

How to create png image from QGraphicsScene in one click on a button , i have a gui and a button named to_png so I want to create a png picture of my QGraphicsScene when I click on this button

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Saving a QGraphicsScene to Svg changes scaling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34183996/saving-a-qgraphicsscene-to-svg-changes-scaling) It is not quite a duplicate, but the question already contains code you can build off of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [`QGraphicsScene::render()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsscene.html#render) allows you to render the scene to a `QPainter`. Therefore, you can just render it into a `QImage`. This is actually mentioned in the documentation of `QGraphicsScene::render()`.

Untested example:

```cpp
QImage image;
QPainter painter(&image);
painter.setRenderHint(QPainter::Antialiasing);
scene.render(&painter);
image.save("screenshot.png")
```

Comment: this code will be in here ? 



    void Name_of_class::on_to_png _clicked(){here}

Comment: Unfortunately you haven't showed us any of your code. But in general yes: You want this to be in the slot that get's called by your `QPushButton`'s `clicked()` signal.